# SQL- how to pick consecutive rows?

Tags: sql

I want to pick the IDs when the two conditions are met

1. Col2 of every ID should have 1 and
2. the consecutive row of same ID should be 2

it does not matter where 1 is but 2 must be the consecutive row after 1.

| IDs | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 97654 | 1 |
| 97854 | 2 |
| 97854 | 3 |
| 97854 | 4 |
| 97854 | 5 |
| 76543 | 1 |
| 76543 | 3 |
| 76543 | 2 |
| 12345 | 2 |
| 12345 | 3 |
| 12345 | 4 |
| 34567 | 3 |
| 34567 | 1 |
| 34567 | 2 |

output

| IDs |
| --- |
| 97854 |
| 34567 |

I tried to use this code but here it outputs all the IDs

```
SELECT *
from            (SELECT IDs, Col2 FROM table_name where Col2 = 1)a
left outer join (SELECT IDs, Col2 FROM table_name where Col2 = 2)b
             on a.IDs=b.IDs
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't spam tags, each DBMS has very different syntax and you'll attract people that can't help you really, while the post is more likely to get downvotes and closed. Use only **one** DBMS tag relative to the one you're using.

Comment: Change that LEFT OUTER JOIN to an INNER JOIN and I think you would have what you are after (although there are other ways to write this logic).

Comment: Without an ORDER BY there is no such thing as "before" or "after" in a relational database. In the absence of an ORDER BY the database engine is free to return your data in whatever order it finds convenient. That might correspond to the order in which rows were entered into the database, or it might not. A partial ordering, such as ORDER BY IDs in your example data, leaves the database engine free to return the rows with the Col2 values ordered however it likes. So given the table layout above there's no way to supply an answer which will work for arbitrary data.

Comment: @JNevill just using INNER JOIN is not solving my problem. Yes, Inner join fetches all the IDs having 1 and 2 in Col2 but not in consecutive manner :(

Comment: How are you ordering your rows to get them to be "Consecutive" as in your sample data. No table has an inherent ordering and with the only two columns you've shared there is no way to suggest that `2` directly follows `1` for any particular `ID`. How are you getting them to be in that order?

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are asking for you should use window functions. Make it row_number or lead ones.

One option is:

```sql
SELECT t0.IDs
from (select *, ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY IDs) as rn from table_name) t0
left join (select *, ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY IDs) as rn from table_name) t1 on (t0.IDs = t1.IDs AND t0.rn + 1 = t1.rn)
where t0.Col2=1 and t1.Col2=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table with itself. Each instance picks row #1 and row #2 respectively, and the join ensures both are present.

For example:

```
select t.ids
from t
join t b on b.ids = t.ids
where t.col2 = 1 and b.col2 = 2
```